# Rendertarget and alphablending problem (Offscreen particle rendering)

Tags: directx, directx11, particles, alpha-blending

Today, I have implemented soft particles by rendering them to a separate render target and blending that with the scene, which worked as expected with additive blended particles. In that case I render the particles to a rendertarget while blending them additively, then drawing that rendertarget in fron of the scene while blending additively, works like a charm, I even save some render time if I use a smaller render target.
In the case of alpha blended particles, I have a serious issue. First I draw them with a blend state set up for alpha blending:

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC bd;
bd.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable=true;
bd.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
bd.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
bd.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
bd.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO;
bd.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
bd.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
bd.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = 0x0f;
bd.IndependentBlendEnable=true;
```

(This is it after reading the [GPU Gems article on this subject.](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch23.html))

The render target which I draw them to is cleared by zero for all channels. When I draw this rendertarget to the screen I use a blend state set up for alphablending (it is used for all the 2d images and definetly works well) and I get this: [image] It seems as if I have depth writing turned on but I made sure it is turned off.
If I draw the rendertarget with these alpha blended particles on it, but with no blending (for the RT) I get this: [image] Which seems correct, it just doesn't blend how I want to. On GPU gems there are sure some well described formulas for the blending, but if I set the blendstate descibed there I won't get the results they get. Could someone help me with what I am missing?

Comment: Damn... I have tried changing settings for a whole day, posted this and the next minute I try setting the blendstate's SrcBlendAlpha to D3D11_BLEND_ONE and it works. Though I don't understand why, if anyone describes I am accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because  you  first blend  particle    color  with  black  render  target  use  src_alpha

so the  image in the  render target is multiply  alpha  yet
when you  use  the  render  target   you  should  not  multiply  alpha  again  or it  will  dark the   part of  the   image where  alpha  is low